# Difference between Evaluate and SetVariable when working with Dictionaries, RobotFramework

Tags: python, dictionary, robotframework

I am using a dictionary in Robot Framework and trying to get the value when the key is given. It seems to work when i use the "SetVariable" command but not when I use the "Evaluate" command. 
I am also using Python 2.7 and RIDE to work with Robot framework. I've searched the internet for an answer but haven't had any luck

```
** Variables **

&{Units_Lookup}    0=1    1=2    2=3    3=4    4=5    5=0    b=2

** Test Cases **

Experiment
    ${Counter}    Set Variable    1
    ${Value}    Set Variable    &{Units_Lookup}[${Counter}]
    Log To Console    \r${Value}
    ${Counter}    Evaluate    0+1
    ${Value}    Set Variable    &{Units_Lookup}[${Counter}]
    Log To Console    \r${Value}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to know the difference of your variable types. In Python there is a difference between a String and an Integer. In your dictionary example the keys were strings, and the result from evaluate was an integer. Converting all integers to their true type in the below example:

```
** Variables **

&{Units_Lookup}    ${0}=1    ${1}=2    ${2}=3    ${3}=4    ${4}=5    ${5}=0    b=2

** Test Cases **

Experiment
    ${Counter}    Set Variable    ${1}
    ${Value}    Set Variable    &{Units_Lookup}[${Counter}]
    Log To Console    \r${Value}
    ${Counter}    Evaluate    0+1
    ${Value}    Set Variable    &{Units_Lookup}[${Counter}]
    Log To Console    \r${Value}
```

Should you be working with existing code, then altering the last `Set Variable` statement to convert the `${counter}` to `${Counter.__str__()}` will work to convert the result from `Evaluate` too.

```
** Variables **

&{Units_Lookup}    0=1    1=2    2=3    3=4    4=5    5=0    b=2

** Test Cases **

Experiment
    ${Counter}    Set Variable    1
    ${Value}    Set Variable    &{Units_Lookup}[${Counter}]
    Log To Console    \r${Value}
    ${Counter}    Evaluate    0+1
    ${Value}    Set Variable    &{Units_Lookup}[${Counter.__str__()}]
    Log To Console    \r${Value}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! 
I originally thought about the scalar type and was trying to use the keyword "BuiltIn.Convert To String" to turn it into a string but was unable to do so